# Codeigniter session in sub directory

Tags: codeigniter, session

I am using CI version 3 with session driver as files. I just want to get session variables in some sub directory but print_r($_SESSION) not printing my saved session variables.

Can some one help how do i get session in sub-directory.

In addition, I have tried below and getting some variable checking set or not but don't know how to get all variables value from saved session files that I am saving in my tmp folder at root

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['ci_session'])) {
$file = '../tmp/ci_session'.$_COOKIE['ci_session'];
if(file_exists($file)){
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($file));
    //echo $contents;
    $pos = strpos($contents, 'logged_in');

    if ($pos === false) {
        echo "Logged out";
    } else {
        echo "Logged in";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

}

Comment: Did you read the usage instructions embedded in the code comments just above the session's configuration settings?

Comment: Actullay, I have wordpress directory as blog under CI. Now, whenever someone login in CI, want to get logged in session data under blog. My session save path is $config['sess_save_path'] = 'tmp'; tmp folder is at root.Is that path fine ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your config.php file configuration where you want to get your all session data

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH.'test';
```

Above config will store all sessions in application/test directory

Comment: My session save path is $config['sess_save_path'] = 'tmp'; tmp folder is at root but I want session check all of my sub directory. I have blog folder at root